# Calculate YEAR of a past date without YEAR in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I extract dates from a log file which doesn't include the year.
The only known fact is that the date is in the past.  Could be 1 second ago, but not longer than 365 days ago.

I like to calculate the year.

logfile date format is

```
date('m-d H:i:s');
```

If the current date would be '1 April 2018', 
log file '1 Jan' would be '1 Jan 2018'.

However when the log file date reads

```
'20 Dec'  I need '20 Dec 2017'
'2 Apr'   I need  '2 Apr 2017' (as 2 Apr 2018 would be in the future)
'1 Apr'   I need  '1 Apr 2018' (that's today)
```

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Create the date, and check if the date is higher than the current one. If it is, subtract a year from it.

Comment: Good luck with the special cases for leap years and DST

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this snippet as a starting point :

```
$today = date('m-d H:i:s');
$dates = array(
    '04-20 15:00:00',
    '02-03 15:00:00',
    '05-12 15:00:00',
    '01-14 15:00:00',
    '02-15 15:00:00',
);

echo $today.'<br>';

foreach($dates as &$date) {
    $exploded = explode(' ',$date);
    if($date > $today) {
        $date = $exploded[0].'-2017 '.$exploded[1];
        echo $date . '<br>';
    } else {
        $date = $exploded[0].'-2018 '.$exploded[1];
        echo $date . '<br>';
    }
}
```

it should output something like this :

03-26 11:49:33

04-20-2017 15:00:00

02-03-2018 15:00:00

05-12-2017 15:00:00

01-14-2018 15:00:00

02-15-2018 15:00:00

Comment: I'm pretty sure that comparing something like `01-14 15:00:00` against a Unix timestamp is not going to be particularly reliable...

Comment: i was thinking it's not gonna be an issue since the today date is generated without the year in it so the comparison can be done

Comment: Not really since a Unix timestamp (as you'd get from `date()`) is specifically the number of seconds since midnight on the 1st of January 1970 - so you're comparing something like `1522138947` to `05-12 15:00:00`

Comment: For me date() returns a string formatted according to the given format string from an Unix timestamp; So it will return `03-26 11:49:33` as in the exemple. I may be wrong but then i don't get why my snippet's working

Comment: ... oh gawd - ignore me, my brain's obviously gone to sleep, you're right... I'm probably thinking of `time()` - I've basically only used `DateTime` for so long I've forgotten how the other functions work :|

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
function convertMonthStringToInt($strMonth) {
   $month = array(
       'Jan' => 0,
       'Feb' => 1,
       'Mar' => 2,
       'Apr' => 3,
       'May' => 4,
       'Jun' => 5,
       'Jul' => 6,
       'Aug' => 7,
       'Sep' => 8,
       'Oct' => 9,
       'Nov' => 10,
       'Dec' => 11,
   );

   return $month[$strMonth];
}

function findYear($monthLog) {
   $currentYear = date('Y');
   $currentMonth = date('M');

   if(convertMonthStringToInt($monthLog) > convertMonthStringToInt($currentMonth)) {
      return $currentYear - 1;
   }
   else {
      return $currentYear;
   }
}
```

then you can use findYear function to find the correct year

```
findYear('Nov'); // 2017
findYear('Jan'); // 2018
findYear('Mar'); //2018
findYear('Aug'); // 2017
```

etc...